# Concat dataframe contain the same string

Tags: python, dataframe

Having:

```
combine_by = ['aaa', 'ccc']
dfs_list = [df_aaa_1, df_aaa_2, df_ccc_1, df_ccc_2, df_ggg_1]
```

How can I combine the **dataframes** with the same string from the **'combine by'** list in **df.name**? and get..

```
result = [df_aaa_1+2, df_ccc_1+2, df_ggg_1]
```

Comment: I think he meant merge or concat

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make the `dfs_list` into strings to compare them with the `combine_by` list. You need to either manually make `dfs_list` a string, or name the dataframes using `df.name` which is a more suitable option.

So:

```
df_aaa_1.name = "df_aaa_1"
df_aaa_2.name = "df_aaa_2"
```

Then compare each dataframe's name with the `combine_by` list using a simple for loop if else statement:

```
combine_by_aaa = []
combine_by_ccc = []

df_aaa = pd.DataFrame()
df_ccc = pd.DataFrame()

def merge_dfs(frames):
    for df in frames:
        if "aaa" in df.name:
            combine_by_aaa.append(df)
        if "ccc" in df.name:
            combine_by_ccc.append(df)
    
    try:
        df_aaa = pd.concat(combine_by_aaa)
        df_ccc = pd.concat(combine_by_ccc)
    except ValueError:
    pass
        

merge_dfs(dfs_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try something like this, though it looks very convoluted .

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 1], ['b', 2]],
                   columns=['letter', 'number'])
df1.name = 'aaa_1'
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['c', 3], ['d', 4]],
                   columns=['letter', 'number'])
df2.name='aaa_3'
df3 = pd.DataFrame([['e', 3], ['f', 4]],
                   columns=['letter', 'number'])
df3.name='bbb_2'
df4 = pd.DataFrame([['g', 3], ['h', 4]],
                   columns=['letter', 'number'])
df4.name='bbb_4'


df_list = [df1, df2, df3, df4]

def combine_2df(df_list, string):
    filtered_df = [df for df in df_list if string in df.name]
    df = pd.concat(filtered_df)
    df.name = string+"_"+"+".join([df.name.split("_")[-1] for df in filtered_df])
    #edit this as you need to return whatever name format you want
    return df
    
df5 = combine_2df(df_list, 'aaa')
print(df5.name)
```

this gives a result df5 with df.name `aaa_1+3`